# Typescript init object with generic

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typescript-generics

What I want is something like this :

```
class ThemeExample <T> {
    static theme : T;
    static init(theme : T){
        ThemeExample.theme = theme;
    }
};

//config it 
ThemeExample.init({
    hello : 'hi'
})
//in another file access properties with auto completion
ThemeExample.theme.hello
```

But this doesn't work. `TS2302: Static members cannot reference class type parameters.`

Tried a few other things such as making the class in a function and return it, and use functions generic in the class.
Still couldn't find a way that would let me initialize this config once.
And then access the theme later and get auto completion for all its properties in other files.
I need something like this please help me, I'm too frustrated.

Comment: I doubt you'll get anything better than [a factory function where you export what it returns](https://tsplay.dev/mxo78N).  You can't easily mutate the state of a single variable, and even if you do that, there's no mechanism to have such state changes persist across file boundaries; you would need to export a `const` "configured version" and import it in different files.  If that meets your needs I can write up an answer; otherwise I can only imagine a "this is impossible, sorry" answer.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the quick response, right now you have the function and export const in the same file.Could it be possible to do this but instead of creating and exporting in the same file, create in a file and export in another?Because this class is supposed to go in a module eventually the initialization however must stay on user's side.

Comment: ? Yes, the TS Playground only supports one file.  If you want to provide me with a link to  a [mcve] web IDE project that I can fork and modify, I'll show you.  You can export the factory function in your module, and in another file you can import the factory, create the class, and export that class, and in a third file you can import the created class.  But in order to show this I need a multi-file IDE link

Comment: Thank you! https://codesandbox.io/ could do the job, but anyways if you post the example code as an answer that would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static side of a `class` consists of the class constructor, and there is exactly one such constructor.  It has no access to any generic parameters on the instance type, because a class constructor needs to be able to create instances for any possible specification of that generic parameter.  In your `ThemeExample<T>` code, the class constructor must be able to make instances of, say, `ThemeExample<string>` and `ThemeExample<number>`.  If you could have a static property of type `T`, it would mean that it would have to be *both* a `string` and a `number` and any other possible type for `T`.  It doesn't work.

Conceptually you could imagine `ThemeExample` as having a `static` property named `theme` of type `unknown`, and then when you call `ThemeExample.init("hello")`, the compiler would [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the `ThemeExample` class constructor so that `theme` is now of type `string` instead of `unknown`.  But there is no good mechanism to do this.  You could imagine writing something like an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) which would have such an effect:

```
interface ThemeExampleConstructor<T = unknown> {
  theme: T;
  init<T>(theme: T): asserts this is ThemeExampleConstructor<T>;
  new(): ThemeExample<T>;
}

declare const ThemeExample: ThemeExampleConstructor;

ThemeExample.theme.toUpperCase(); // error
ThemeExample.init("hello");
ThemeExample.theme.toUpperCase(); // okay
new ThemeExample().instanceProp.toUpperCase(); // okay
```

But you can't do it with `class` syntax, and even if you got this done, narrowing like this doesn't work across file boundaries or even function boundaries.  There's no mechanism whereby the compiler would see that `ThemeExample.init("hello")` in one file happens *before* the `ThemeExample.theme.toUpperCase()` in another file.  So we can't do this at all.

---

Instead I'd suggest going the route of a factory function which produces new class constructors.  This function would exist in some library, say **`Library/index.ts`**:

```
export function initThemeExample<T>(theme: T) {
    return class ThemeExample {
        static theme = theme;
    };
}
```

Then in another file like **`userLib.ts`**, a user could `import` that from the library, configure, and re-export:

```
import {initThemeExample} from './Library'

//config it 
export const ThemeExample = initThemeExample({
    hello: 'hi'
})
```

And then the user could use this configured constructor in all other files:

```
import {ThemeExample} from './userLib'

//import your ThemeExaple in another file
document.write(ThemeExample.theme.hello.toUpperCase()); // HI
```

---

[Link to StackBlitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-webtvx?file=index.ts)

Comment: Disappointed that this is not possible after one day of trying. But your alternative is brilliant and creative.I use it as it is the best option currently available. Thank you so much.